# 74HC08N doesn't latch

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, ttl, logic-level

[image]

I am using the 74HC08N chip. Why doesn't the first AND gate latch itself?

I have connected the output of the first AND gate to its own input.

I have used two resistors, the one on top is a pull-up and the one in the bottom is the pull-down

After I release the button, the diode should take care by feeding the current from the output back into the input.  Why  doesn't this happen.  The LED is not always turned on after I press the button once.

[image]

Comment: please draw the schematic diagram of the circuit

Comment: Where is your decoupling?

Comment: Those prototyping boards often are quite bad and gives you lots of bad contacts.

Comment: @jsotola i have added a picture

Comment: @winny i am not sure what decoupling means , what is it actually ?

Comment: @Damien really ?

Comment: I spent so much time trying to debug circuit whilst it was just bad connections, depends of the quality of your breadboard, but below 150$ don't expect to have something good. The good ones are expensive. Also components that come on glued tape like resistor and leds often have glue residue on the pins that gets into the contacts, so better cut them. I personally rarely use them and prefer to do a PCB or use a veroboard.

Answer (score 2):

you must connect the LED through a resistor to the ground:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Paul Ghobril, your solution worked perfectly !

Comment: @Kandyboy - Hi, Your comment suggests that you have received as much help as you need. In order to mark the topic as solved, please consider ["accepting" the answer which most helped you](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the "tick mark" ("check mark") next to that answer, to turn it green). Although accepting an answer isn't mandatory, it is *encouraged* to do so as your question is then clearly shown as being answered in various lists, it shows that you aren't waiting for more answers, and we don't get nagged for it being a question without an accepted answer. Thanks!